# Jenkins webapp deployment

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, deployment, jenkins

I have the web project which is compiled on Jenkins. It consists of a couple of wars and jars. And it is deploing on tomcat, jars are going in the lib dir and wars in the webapps dir. 
The proplem is, how to make autodeploy by Jenkins if I need to put jars in /libs dir on tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you create a Jenkins slave on the target machine?  If so, you can either:

1. use the Deploy plugin and then trigger a job which executes a shell script on the slave to rearrange the JARs
2. run the deployment completely from the slave (pulling the JARs and WARs from your Jenkins master and using shell scripts to deploy to the local Tomcat).

Thank you

Comment: Thank you. I've think alot about how to do this. So we (our team) decided to make ant script, which takes all results and puts it on server. The question was, could we do it without any handmade scripts. thank you again.